# How to derive a marginal cost curve

Tags: cost

Provide a mathematical proof for the general result that, given a linear average curve, the corresponding marginal curve must have the same vertical intercept but will be twice as steep as the average curve

Comment: Hi, welcome to Economics SE. We tend to ask users to give some evidence that they have tried to do things that look like homework questions before just posting a question. The guidelines are readily available to you in the help section.

Answer (score 2):

That comment said, I can provide an answer here.

Take an average cost function:

$$f(x) = mx + b$$ where x is output, b is the intercept, and m is the gradient.

So total cost is:

$$C(x) = x(mx + b) = mx^2 + bx$$

And that makes marginal cost the derivative of this function:

$$C'(x) = 2mx + b$$

Best of luck with your homework.

Comment: If you disagree with your own comment you don't have to say it, if you agree with the comment why do you answer?

Comment: "We _tend_ to ask users"... Sometimes we can give new people a break I think.